# Question about text after iframe

Tags: html

I have this test html page, I tried it in both chrome and firefox.

```
<html>
<body>

before iframe

<iframe width="300" height="300" src="http://www.yahoo.com"/>

after iframe

</body>
</html>
```

But what i see is I see the text 'before iframe', but I don't see the text 'after iframe'.

Can you please tell how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An iframe is **not a self closing element**, specify the end tag.

```
<iframe src="" width="" height=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Nitpick: it's self-closing (or self-terminating) tag, not self-closing element :)

Comment: This.  If I had remembered this, I would have saved myself 3 hours of searching our javascript for what was killing the following elements.

Answer (score 1):

Iframes can't be self-closing, they need a closing tag. One of the oddities of HTML.

In other words, do this: `<iframe src="blah"></iframe>`, not this: `<iframe src="blah" />`

Same goes for `script` and `textarea` tags and probably others I'm forgetting at the moment.