# The page does not render fully in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Any idea why this page is not rendering full in my Chrome v 13 dev ?

http://madhur.github.com/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html

View source shows full HTML code but does not render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/4XpnKHJAok8' frameborder='0' height='349' width='425' />
```

to

```
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/4XpnKHJAok8' frameborder='0' height='349' width='425'></iframe>
```

fixed the issue. An iframe tag is not self closing, see this SO thread [Question about text after iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269706/question-about-text-after-iframe)

EDIT: 
You said it still didn't render so I pulled the source for the page and tested locally in IE & Chrome. Making the one change I mentioned above allowed the rest of the page to render. Here is the complete source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Github as a development platform &#8211; Madhur Ahuja</title>
   <meta name="author" content="Madhur Ahuja" />

     <link rel="start" href="/" />




    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="atom.xml" title="RSS feed" />


   <!-- syntax highlighting CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://madhur.github.com/files/css/syntax.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://madhur.github.com/files/css/global.css" type="text/css" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://madhur.github.com/files/css/layout.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://madhur.github.com/files/css/non-blog.css" type="text/css" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://madhur.github.com/files/css/blog.css" />





   <!-- Homepage CSS -->

<script src="http://madhur.github.com/files/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://madhur.github.com/files/js/site.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23769089-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body id="">
<div id="gradient">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">

        <div id="logo">
<h2>
    Madhur@Web:~# :(){ :|: &amp; };:

</h2>

</div>


<div id="navigation">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a class="home" href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="blog" href="/blogindex.html">Blog</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a class="work" href="/work">Resume</a></li>-->
                    <li><a class="code" href="/code">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a class="papers" href="/papers">Papers</a></li>
                    <li><a class="info" href="/info">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="contact" href="/contact">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>


</div>
<div class="c">
&nbsp;
</div>



<!--
<div id="dash">
<div id="intro">

                        <p>You're currently viewing the personal website of <a href="/">Madhur</a>, This website is inpired from
                        Tom Preston Werner's blog post <a href="http://tom.preston-werner.com/2008/11/17/blogging-like-a-hacker.html">"Blogging like a Hacker"</a>. A huge thanks to him for creating <a href="https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll">Jekyll</a>.</p>
                    </div>

                    <p id="feed">Subscribe to <a href="/blog/feed">posts</a> or <a href="/blog/comments/feed">comments</a></p>
                    <p id="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/madhur25" title="tweet tweet!">Follow me on Twitter</a></p>
                    <div class="c">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
-->



        </div>
        <div id="content">

          <div id="primary">

    <div id="blogcontent">

        <div class="postmeta full">

         <p class="timestamp">11 June 2011

<br>
<span class="time">05:00 PM</span>
</p> 

<div class="actions">
<ul> 
                                <li><a href="/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html#disqus_thread" data-disqus-identifier="/2011/06/03/githubplatform/" class="comment">View Comments</a></li> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var disqus_developer = 1;
    var disqus_shortname = 'madhur';
    var disqus_iframe_css = "http://madhur.github.com/css/screen.css";
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var query = '?';

                query += 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) + '&';
                //alert(query);


document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/madhur/get_num_replies.js?url2=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.url) + '#disqus_thread"></' + 'script>');


</script>


                                <li><span class="share" title="Click to expand">share this post</span> 
                                    <ul class="sharing" style="display:none"> 
                                        <li class="first"><a href="http://blinklist.com/index.php?Action=Blink/addblink.php&amp;Url=/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html&amp;Title=Github as a development platform" id="share_blinklist" title="Share on BlinkList" rel="nofollow">BlinkList</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="http://del.icio.us/post?url=http://madhur.github.com/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html&amp;title=Github as a development platform" id="share_delicious" title="Add to del.icio.us" rel="nofollow">del.icio.us</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="http://digg.com/submit?url=http://madhur.github.com/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html" id="share_digg" title="Digg This!" rel="nofollow">Digg</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://madhur.github.com/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html" id="share_facebook" title="Share on Facebook" rel="nofollow">Facebook</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=http://madhur.github.com/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html&amp;title=Github as a development platform" id="share_reddit" title="Share on Reddit" rel="nofollow">Reddit</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://madhur.github.com/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html&amp;title=Github as a development platform" id="share_stumbleupon" title="Share on StumbleUpon" rel="nofollow">StumbleUpon</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=http://madhur.github.comGithub as a development platform%3A%20/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html" id="share_twitter" title="Tweet this!" rel="nofollow">Twitter</a></li> 
                                        <li class="last"><a href="http://www.technorati.com/faves?add=http://madhur.github.com/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html" id="share_technorati" title="Favourite on Technorati" rel="nofollow">Technorati</a></li> 
                                    </ul> 
                                </li> 
                                <li><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/madhur
" class="subscribe">subscribe to this blog</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/blog//trackback" class="trackback" rel="trackback">post a trackback</a></li>                              <li><a href="/blog/2011/06/11/githubplatform.html" class="permalink">permalink</a></li> 
                                                            </ul> 

</div>


        </div>

        <div class="post full">
 <h1 id='github_as_a_development_platform'>Github as a development platform</h1>

<p>Currently <a href='http://github.com'>Github</a> is an emerging and exciting platform for development. For those who don&#8217;t know what Github is, here is the definition straight from <a href='wikipedia.com'>wikipedia</a></p>

<p><em>GitHub is a web-based hosting service for software development projects that use the Git revision control system</em></p>

<p>Git is a <strong>distributed</strong> revision control system created by none other than Linus Torvalds. The beauty of Git lies in its distributed nature which is different from other traditional revision control systems. Git gives each developer a local copy of the entire development history, and changes are copied from one such repository to another. These changes are imported as additional development branches, and can be merged in the same way as a locally developed branch. The distributed nature of Git also requires that code by merged much often that other systems and for that reason much of the implementation of Git has is in C programming language. In this video of Linus Torvalds at Google, he talks about how easy it is to merge thousands of lines of code in Git.</p>
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/4XpnKHJAok8' frameborder='0' height='349' width='425' ></iframe>
<p>Coming back to Github, it provides social networking functionality such as feeds, followers and the network graph to display how developers work on their versions of a repository. Users can also create wikis for individual repositories and static web pages which can served by static web site generator <a href='https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki'>Jekyll</a>. Infact the source of the site you are viewing right now is hosted on Github <a href='https://github.com/madhur/madhur.github.com'>repository</a>.</p>

<div class="blocked tags">
<p>

    <a href="/categories/Github.html">Github</a>
,

    <a href="/categories/Code.html">Code</a>
,

</p>
</div>
<div class="hr"></div>


<!-- Discus Comments -->
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>


<!-- Enable Disqus comments -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var disqus_shortname = 'madhur';
  var disqus_identifier = '/2011/06/03/githubplatform/';
  var disqus_title = 'Github as a development platform';
  (function() {
      var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
      dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
      (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>


        </div>

        <div class="c">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>


</div>


<!--<div id="extra">

</div>-->




<div class="c">&nbsp;</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var disqus_shortname = 'madhur'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function () {
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
    }());
</script>







        </div>

          <div id="footer">

                <p id="copyright">
                    Content &amp; Design by 
                    <a href="/info/">Madhur Ahuja</a>
                    &copy; 2010-2011
                    (Some rights reserved)          
                </p>
                <p id="poweredby">
                    Powered by 
                    <a href="http://github.com/mreid/jekyll/" title="A static, minimalist CMS">Jekyll</a> and <a href="http://disqus.com">Disqus</a>.
                </p>

                <div class="c">&nbsp;</div>


          </div>

<p style="text-align:center">
    <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img
      src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Strict" height="31" width="88" /></a>
  </p>

    </div>

</div>


<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    /*Load jQuery if not already loaded*/ if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){ document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\"   src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js\"></"+"script>"); var __noconflict = true; } 
    var IE6UPDATE_OPTIONS = {
        icons_path: "http://static.ie6update.com/hosted/ie6update/images/"
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ie6update.com/hosted/ie6update/ie6update.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just checked your link again and the iframe tag is still not properly closed.

Comment: Its closed in the source, but its not closed in actual view source in Chrome

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't render in firefox 3.6.13 either.

I think your problem is here:

```
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/4XpnKHJAok8' frameborder='0' height='349' width='425' />
```

You haven't closed your iframe tag.

Answer (score 1):

It renders fine in Chrome 12, which is the official release.
If the dev version is displaying a problem, you should really be getting in touch with the Chrome dev/bug community, not trying to figure out what's wrong with your page. (After first making sure you didn't cause this yourself; there are more than a few validation errors in your document to start with.)